# Are there workflow engines that can reason about what are the next possible options?

Tags: workflow

I am wondering if there exists a workflow engine, that can tell you what are the possible options. 'traditional' engines want you to specify the form before hand in every step, but I am looking for an engine that can tell you what possible steps are next so the buttons on screen can be adjusted accordingly.

Say, you are in a step with two possible routes out of there, I would like the engine to tell me something so I can decide to create a button that leads to step 2a and a button that leads to step 2b. Possibly the set of buttons could differ based on your role.

Does that make sense?